# How can I search for {{.*}} and replace with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, templates

I am trying to create my own javascript simple template function
I want to create a html page that will look like this

```
<p>
{{HELLO_WORLD}}
<br />
{{MY_NAME_IS}}
</p>
```

and than with javascript to replace anything that is in {{}}
with a json var that will look like this

```
{HELLO_WORLD: "Hello World!", MY_NAME_IS: "My name is"}
```

I am a little confused about the right method to do this.
the point is to make a multilanguage web site, that way I load the json for the desired language.
thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript supports regular expression-based find-and-replace, with functions for the replacement. So you can do this:

```
myInputString.replace( /\{\{([^\}]*)\}\}/g, function( s, v ) { return myJSON[v] } );
```

To explain:

`replace` takes 2 arguments. The first is a regular expression object. In this case we build one inline using JavaScript's `/expression/flags` syntax. It looks for 2 opening braces (which need to be escaped because they have special meaning in regular expressions) followed by any characters which are not a closing brace, followed by 2 closing braces. The `g` means "global", so that it will match all cases rather than just the first one.

When a match is found, the function will be called. The first argument (I called it `s`) is the full matched string (like "{{abc}}"), the second (I called it `v`) is set to the first bit in brackets (like "abc").

In real code, you should add error checking (variables which don't exist), and possibly convert to lowercase / whatever.

Full details on `replace` are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace